# Axios delete not working , It is showing pending status in network tab in chorme

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

I'm using axios Delete method to delete my record. When I'm sending request , it is not returning any response. I was seen in networktab in chrome, there the API status is pending state. I'm using Redux and React. Below is my code

I'm importing service.js file in Action.js

```
   Action.js file
    const delete = formData => {
      return async dispatch => {
      const data = deleteservice.deleteRetail(formData)
      .then({
         console.log(response)
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
       })
      }
   }

   service.js
   export const deleteRetail = (formData) => {
   return axios({
   method: 'DELETE,
   URL : myURL,
   headers: {
     'content-type' : 'application/json'
   },
   data : { 
    userID: 'test',
    userName : 'test'

    }
   })
  }
```

This is my code, While I'm calling this delete url , status showing as pending in network. not getting any response.
Please suggest me the solution

Comment: issue is probably on the server side.

Comment: No, I'm calling API from React service file using axios method, While I'm checking in postman it is working fine